# Cannot display nested namespace in GDB on Android

Tags: gdb, android-source

I'm having problems trying to display a nested namespace in gdb on Android. I'm trying to investigate the ART framework (symbols contained primarily in libart.so and libandroid_runtime.so on the emulator)

I'm interested in investigating the class "Class" in ART. It is under the art::mirror:: namespace.

Here's my setup:

```
1) Built a Marshmallow version of the AOSP with debug symbols
2) Launched the emulator with my AOSP build
3) Used gdbclient to connect to a running process (com.android.musicfx-- arbitrary, but uses the Android runtime)
4) Used set solib-search-path in gdb to the same place my library symbols are.
```

This loads libart.so and libandroid_runtime.so (among lots of others). However, whenever I try to cast and print a section of memory to a "Class" class, it fails:

```
(gdb) p/x *(art::mirror::Class*) 0xbed1af38
No type "mirror" within class or namespace "art".
```

"mirror" is most certainly within "art". It's the foundation of the Java <-> C translation in the ART runtime: see http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/art/runtime/mirror/class.cc and http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/art/runtime/mirror/class.h

Where am I going wrong? The author of https://vaioco.github.io/art/art-part-i/ does essentially the same thing, and it seems to work for him.

Comment: I found a little trick that seems to work. By doing a "f 4" (jumping 4 function calls back in the stack), into an art function, I can use these functions as intended. Still no idea why I can't do it where my breakpoint is set.